# How to get traffic of a VM in ESXi

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, network-traffic, esx

I want to get the traffic usage of a specified VM over the last month.
I have access to the ESXi and its command prompt and also I have added the ESXi to a VCeter server and have access to it too. Is there any way to get the desired value in a numeric manner in bytes? For example I want to have a number like 100Mb or 1G as the result. Because I want to submit the result to the customer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want Netflow for this. In vSphere it requires the use of a dvSwitch, which I think is limited to certain license levels. You'll also need a collector such as that available from SolarWinds to receive the information so you can see the traffic flows created by the VM.

http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.hostclient.doc/GUID-E19FECAD-8629-4E8A-B61C-1F1C16770B3B.html

http://www.solarwinds.com/netflow-traffic-analyzer

Comment: Thank you @AtomicFireball. I know that way. I am already receiving the netflow with Zabbix and nfdump analyzer. But I wondered to know is there a way to get the traffic as a literal from ESXi itself. I think the answer is Negative. Thank you by the way.

Comment: You might be able to do crude calculations with the performance charts from each machine, but Netflow would be the only real way to obtain true metrics.

Comment: Yes. Netflow is really awesome. Thanks.